# Postgres: calling function with text[] param fails with array literal

Tags: arrays, postgresql, plpgsql

I have a Postgres function that accepts a text[] as input. For example

```
create function temp1(player_ids text[])
    returns void
    language plpgsql
as
$$
begin
    update players set player_xp = 0
    where id in (player_ids);
    -- the body is actually 20 lines long, updating a lot of tables
end;
$$;
```

and I'm trying to call it, but I keep getting

```
[42883] ERROR: operator does not exist: text = text[] Hint: No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts. Where: PL/pgSQL function temp1(text[]) line 3 at SQL statement
```

I have tried these so far

```
select temp1('{F7AWLJWYQ5BMPKGXLMDNQKQ4NY,AQPBAFKQONGLBKIMCSOD747GY4}');
select temp1('{F7AWLJWYQ5BMPKGXLMDNQKQ4NY,AQPBAFKQONGLBKIMCSOD747GY4}'::text[]);
select temp1(array['F7AWLJWYQ5BMPKGXLMDNQKQ4NY,AQPBAFKQONGLBKIMCSOD747GY4']);
select temp1(array['F7AWLJWYQ5BMPKGXLMDNQKQ4NY,AQPBAFKQONGLBKIMCSOD747GY4']::text[]);
```

I have to be missing something obvious...how do I call this function with an array literal?

Comment: `player_ids` is an array variable, not literal. Use `id = any(player_ids)`.

Comment: Ah, it was a problem with the function body, d'oh! I was thinking it was an issue with how I was calling the function. Thanks!

Comment: @klin: Your comment would make a proper answer ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `= any` instead of `in:`

```sql
    ...
    update players set player_xp = 0
    where id = any(player_ids);
    ...
```

[The IN operator](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/functions-comparisons.html#AEN16964) acts on an explicit list of values.

> expression IN (value [, ...])

When you want to compare a value to each element of an array, use [ANY instead.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/functions-comparisons.html#AEN17002)

> expression operator ANY (array expression)

Note that there are variants of both constructs for subqueries [expression IN (subquery)](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/functions-subquery.html#AEN16806) and [expression operator ANY (subquery)](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/functions-subquery.html#AEN16856). The first one was properly used in the other answer though a subquery seems excessive in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You can use unnest function, this function is very easy and same time best performanced. Unnest using for converting array elements to rows. Example:

```
create function temp1(player_ids text[])
    returns void
    language plpgsql
as
$$
begin
    update players set player_xp = 0
    where id in (select pl.id from unnest(player_ids) as pl(id));
    -- the body is actually 20 lines long, updating a lot of tables
end;
$$;
```

And you can easily cast array elements to another type for using unnest.
Example:

```
update players set player_xp = 0
where id in (select pl.id::integer from unnest(player_ids) as pl(id));
```